# Align inputs and textarea with labels vertically even

Tags: html, css

I want to create this form in css

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="contact__right">
  <form action="" class="contact__form">
    <div>
      <label for="name" class="contact__form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email" class="contact__form-label">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="phone" class="contact__form-label">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="message" class="contact__form-label">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="contact__form-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.contact {
  &__form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 105px 95px;
    color: $white;
  }
  &__form-input,
  &__form-textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  &__form-textarea {
    height: 150px;
  }
  &__form-label {
    padding-right: 70px;
  }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is alignment of inputs with labels and of `textarea` at the same line vertically.
`textarea` always sticks out at the side, because of its `label` which has longer text than the rest.

All the help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the compiled CSS (instead of pre-compiled SASS): even better, create an MCVE within your question itself so that we can see what problem you're running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a flexbox for the form, but for each `<div>` inside the form. The labels are vertically centered for each input field, except for the textarea. There the label is vertically aligned at the top. You can play with top padding there when desired.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact__right {
  background-color: gray;
}

.contact__form {
  padding: 105px 95px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.contact__form>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact__form-input,
.contact__form-textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.contact__form-textarea {
  height: 150px;
}

label[for="message"].contact__form-label {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact__right">
  <form action="" class="contact__form">
    <div>
      <label for="name" class="contact__form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email" class="contact__form-label">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="phone" class="contact__form-label">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="message" class="contact__form-label">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="contact__form-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css code and your problem will be solved.

```
.contact__form-label {
vertical-align: top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule for `label`:

```
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

(otherwise label will be treated as an inline-element. This way you give it a fixed width and align it to the top)

If you don't like the alignment at the very top, you can add a `padding-top` ike in the following snippet:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 105px 95px;
  color: $white;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

textarea {
  height: 150px;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 14px;
}
.contact__right {
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact__right">
  <form action="" class="contact__form">
    <div>
      <label for="name" class="contact__form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email" class="contact__form-label">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="phone" class="contact__form-label">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" class="contact__form-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="message" class="contact__form-label">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="contact__form-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
´
```

Answer (score -3):

You are gonna have to do that manually I guess. Normally websites tend to break line after the labels and bring the input fields to the next line.